# Unable to find a specification for `expo-dev-launcher` depended upon by `expo-dev-client` error in EAS

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to build my Expo (bare workflow) app using EAS build and it's failing with the following error:

> Unable to find a specification for `expo-dev-launcher` depended upon
> by `expo-dev-client`

Here's the full message:

> Installing pods Using Expo modules RNFBAnalytics: Using default
> Firebase/Analytics with Ad Ids. May require App Tracking Transparency.
> Not allowed for Kids apps. RNFBAnalytics: You may set variable
> `$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true` in Podfile to use
> analytics without ad ids. Adding a custom script phase for Pod
> RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration Auto-linking React Native modules
> for target `ingridconnect`: A0Auth0, RNCAsyncStorage, RNFBAnalytics,
> RNFBApp, RNFBDynamicLinks, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG,
> RNScreens, expo-dev-client, and react-native-safe-area-context
> Analyzing dependencies Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from
> `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
> Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from
> `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
> RNFBAnalytics: Using default Firebase/Analytics with Ad Ids. May
> require App Tracking Transparency. Not allowed for Kids apps.
> RNFBAnalytics: You may set variable
> `$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true` in Podfile to use
> analytics without ad ids. Fetching podspec for `glog` from
> `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
> Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
>
> CocoaPods 1.11.2 is available. To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
>
> For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG
> for this version at
> https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.2 [!]
>
> [!]Unable to find a specification for `expo-dev-launcher` depended
> upon by `expo-dev-client`
>
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with
> `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.   * mistyped
> the name or version.   * not added the source repo that hosts the
> Podspec to your Podfile.
>
> pod exited with non-zero code: 1

Any idea what the issue is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some `expo-dev-client` dependencies are missing.

Make sure `react-native.config.js` contains the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    ...require('expo-dev-client/dependencies'),
  },
};
```

In my case it was enough to rerun `expo prebuild` command and the file was generated automatically.

Comment: Are there any other possible solutions? I'm getting the same error but I do have the correct contents of `react-native.config.js`

Comment: Using a bare project and this also worked for me to get past the pod install issue